# How to create a document from an Xml string

Tags: xml, webmethods

I would like to transform a xml string (herself constructed from byte array with an external tool.

My document and my input string was all of them created with the same xsd
I read the string with `pub.string:stringToBytes` then I obtain an XmlNode from `pub.xml:xmlStringToXMLNode`

This part works well.

I would after that create a document, call it Doc.
I call `pub.xml:xmlNodeToDocument`. But the document returned is not in the correct type.
I mean that all datas are correct with correct name, but when I tried to map some data to another document, it never works.

I know it's not clear, sorry for that.
So, in details, I have a simple xsd :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:complexType name="EtdDaCisIUpdParty">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="wUpdatetsMax">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="15"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="wTpsnEtendu" type="WTpsnEtendu"/>
      <xs:element name="wTpsnExt" type="WTpsnExt" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="WTpsnEtendu">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="WTpsnExt">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="EtdDaCisIUpdParty" type="EtdDaCisIUpdParty" />

</xs:schema>
```

And a correspondant xml string conforming to this xsd :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mstns:EtdDaCisIUpdParty  xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" >
    <mstns:wUpdatetsMax>40</mstns:wUpdatetsMax> 
    <mstns:wTpsnEtendu>
        <mstns:Id>13</mstns:Id>
        <mstns:Name>Test</mstns:Name>
    </mstns:wTpsnEtendu>
    <mstns:wTpsnExt>
        <mstns:key>1</mstns:key>
        <mstns:value>one</mstns:value>
    </mstns:wTpsnExt>
    <mstns:wTpsnExt>
        <mstns:key>2</mstns:key>
        <mstns:value>something</mstns:value>
    </mstns:wTpsnExt>
    <mstns:wTpsnExt>
        <mstns:key>3</mstns:key>
        <mstns:value>nothing</mstns:value>
    </mstns:wTpsnExt>
</mstns:EtdDaCisIUpdParty>
```

A document generated with the same xsd :
[image]

Then I have a Flow service that transform an xml string to the document

[image]

It seems to works but it is not.
If I add a simple map, it was never processed :

[image]

The pipeline in result never contains the value of the last map. After using debug mode, i understand that the resulting document of `pub.xml:xmlStringToXMLNode` is not the same type of my doc.

[image]

The `Id` string in the pipeline out is missing.

What's wrong with my understanding and with my example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is in the subtle differences of the `mstns:EtdDaCisIUpdParty` variable's data structure between your 2nd and 3rd screenshots:

Your 2nd screenshot shows the data structure as per the document reference you used when you declared the variable, which is the design-time view of the structure (what you expect the data structure will look like):

```
- mstns:EtdDaCisIUpdParty
  - mstns:wUpdatetsMax
  - mstns:wTpsnEtendu
  - ...
```

Versus your 3rd screenshot, which shows the actual data structure at run-time:

```
- mstns:EtdDaCisIUpdParty
  - @version
  - @encoding
  - mstns:EtdDaCisIUpdParty
     - mstns:wUpdatetsMax
     - mstns:wTpsnEtendu
     - ...
```

Notice the extra level in the run-time structure, which contains the XML prolog attributes `@version` and `@encoding` and a child document called `mstns:EtdDaCisIUpdParty` representing the root node of your XML document.

Although you have declared your pipeline variable `mstns:EtdDaCisUpdParty` as a document reference, at run-time that doesn't matter and has no effect. Document references let webMethods Designer show you in the GUI the data structure as you expect it to be, which makes it easier for you to work with it at design-time. However, document references are not enforced at run-time.

At run-time, because you've mapped from the top level of `document` to `mstns:EtdDaCisUpdParty`, it has the same structure as `document`, which is different to the document reference you used at design-time. That is why your map step doesn't work. The `mstns:EtdDaCisIUpdParty/mstns:wTpsnEtendu/mstns:Id` variable doesn't actually exist in the pipeline at run-time, and is instead one level deeper in the structure: `mstns:EtdDaCisIUpdParty/mstns:EtdDaCisIUpdParty/mstns:wTpsnEtendu/mstns:Id`.

You can fix your Flow service by mapping from the next level down in the structure instead: `document/mstns:EtdDaCisIUpdParty` --> `mstns:EtdDaCisIUpdParty`, rather than `document` --> `mstns:EtdDaCisIUpdParty`.

Because `document` is a dynamic structure (its structure is known only at run-time since it depends on the XML it parses), you will need to manually create an IData document called `mstns:EtdDaCisIUpdParty` as a child underneath `document` in the **Service Out** pipeline of the call to `pub.xml:xmlNodeToDocument`, and then map from that instead:

1. Right-click on `document` in the **Service Out** pipeline (not the **Pipeline Out** on the right),
2. Insert a new Document variable
3. Name it `mstns:EtdDaCisIUpdParty`
4. Map from `mstns:EtdDaCisIUpdParty` in the **Service Out** pipeline to your variable `mstns:EtdDaCisIUpdParty` in the **Pipeline Out**.

Also, I would recommend that you set the following input parameters in your call to `pub.xml:xmlNodeToDocument`, so that all XML documents are consistently parsed:

- Set `makeArrays` to `false` because it is required if you specify a value for `documentTypeName`
- Set `nsDecls/mstns` to `http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd` so that all XML documents regardless of the namespace prefix used are parsed consistently (prefixes other than `mstns` will still be represented as fields called `mstns:fieldname`; this won't happen unless you declare your namespaces in the `nsDecls` parameter)
- Set `documentTypeName` to the document reference you used to declare the variable `mstns:EtdDaCisIUpdParty` so that XML elements with a `maxOccurs > 1` are treated consistently (always parsed as an array even if the element in question only occurred once in the XML)

And to defend against your service being called with unexpected/unsupported XML documents, you should probably invoke `pub.schema:validate` to ensure the XML is well-formed and valid against the XSD you provided above, or similar.

Comment: Thank you for explanations and solution. It works, and i have understood ;-)